# phpseclib - SFTP - Connection closed by server

Tags: sftp, phpseclib

I'm using [phpseclib](https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib) for connecting from server A to server B using SFTP method.

`$sftp = new phpseclib\Net\SFTP('xxx.xx.xxx.xx');`

And just creating a file within existing directory.

`$res = $sftp->put($filePath, $page_content);`

My `$filePath` and `$page_content` are absolutely okay, no issues with that. The code works properly as well! But the weird part is, the same code sometimes giving the **Connection closed by server** error!

There might be some server dependency or connection timeout issue, but I'm not able to figure out. Anyone have faced same issue and solved it yet?

There are a couple of question threads in StackOverflow, but there are no proper solution. A help here is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the SSH logs. You can get them by doing `define('NET_SSH2_LOGGING', phpseclib\Net\SSH2::LOG_COMPLEX)` before you've initialized the SFTP object and then by doing `echo $sftp->getLog()`

Comment: The log is huge and beyond my limit to get any clue from it! Here's the [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/WvKj322i)

Comment: I apologize for the delay. I extracted the SFTP logs from the SSH2 logs you provided and got this: http://pastebin.com/KrQLqqHR Nothing looks bad in that. The SSH2 server identifies itself as OpenSSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3. Can you connect with any other SFTP client? I'll give you further instructions depending on your answer. Again, apologies for the delay.

Comment: I can connect SSH using putty in Windows or from the Mac terminal. I can also SFTP using the filezilla. Could there be any problem with closing the previous SFTP connection?

Comment: Try it with psftp and see if you can get me the logs from that. You can enable logging by going to PuTTY->Session->Logging and checking the "SSH packets" radio button. Then save the session and then go to psftp and load the session by doing something like "psftp -load sessionName" or something.